# APS plugin for eclipse

Tags: eclipse, plugins, aps

I need to install the APS's plugin in eclipse using the URL present in every APS 1.2 doc:

```
http://www.apsstandard.org/doc/sdk/eclipse-plugin
```

But the url don't work. Is there any other url or way to install it ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plugin compatible with APS 1.x can be installed from this URL: 
http://download.apsstandard.org/ide/2.1/latest

It will not work with latest eclipse though (APS 1.x is now legacy). 
The latest compatible Eclipse version is Luna. You can get it under 'more downloads' on Eclipse website.

Latest version of the APS plugin works with Eclipse Mars but it only supports 2.x packages. More details [here](http://doc.apsstandard.org/2.1/tools/eclipse/setup/).